# Finding and replacing strings in record MySql

Tags: mysql

I have one data sets with inconsistent formatting of text data

One format shows data like:

```
Red Socks (American)
Brewers (American)
etc
```

The other format shows

```
Red Socks - American
Brewers - American
etc
```

I need to clean up one set so that it matches the other set.

I would like to move all the  **Brewers - American** format

I am having trouble writing a query to change **" ("** to **" - "**
And deleting any occurrence of **"("**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace`:

```
update data set field = replace(replace(field, ' (', ' - '), ')', '')
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88db4/1)

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE testing
SET name = REPLACE (name, '(', '- '),
name = REPLACE (name, ')', '')
WHERE name LIKE '%(%'`

Hey, I think this should solve your problem, where 'testing' is the name of table and 'name' is the name of the column.